# How to render a component with different data from different endpoints

Tags: angular, rendering, single-page-application

I've created a simple card component to use it in the dashboard of my application.

The component is just a card with a title and the content of the card it the amount of that registered in the database.

For example: title is Users and the content is "3299 users registered".

Now, how do I use this same component to instead of requesting a hard coded endpoint of users to get the amount of users, I pass something to the component and it uses a different service to get that data.

For example:

```
<simple-card type="users"></simple-card>
<simple-card type="posts"></simple-card>
```

So in the component, I get that "type" and request the according endpoint on my API, so it would show something like this in the screen:

(First Card) Title: users, Content: 3299 users registered
(Second Card) Title: posts, Content: 12388 posts

I know how to retrieve that "type" in the component, and I could just do a switch on that to request the different endpoints, but I don't know if that is the right way to do it (I honestly thought it was a bit hacky).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current solution is totally fine. However, we could do it better by applying a simple pattern. We divide all of our components into two categories: *Container and Presentational components.*

In your case, the `SimpleCardComponent` should be a *Presentational component*. The *Presentational component* only care about how things look, they receive data from their parent and display them.

Assume that we have a *Container component* call `CardGroupComponent` which is the parent of the `SimpleCardComponent` in a component tree. Like this:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-card-group',
  template: `
    <div>
       <app-simple-card title="users" [content]="users"></app-simple-card>
       <app-simple-card title="posts" [content]="posts"></app-simple-card>
    </div>
    `
})
export class CardGroupComponent implements OnInit {
  users: number;
  posts: number;
  ngOnInit(): void {
    // do some api calls and set the value
    // for users and posts
  }
}
```

Then, inside the `SimpleCardComponent` we could retrieve that passed data and display them:

```js
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-simple-card',
  template: `
    <div>
       <h2>Title: {{title}}</h2>
       <p>Content: {{content}}</p>
    </div>
    `
})
export class SimpleCardComponent {
  @Input()
  title: string;
  @Input()
  content: number;
}
```

This way, we can easily reuse our components. Then, to be exact, your question should be "How to effectively reuse an Angular component".

This is a working sample project on CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/2opp3qn56y

For more information about this simple pattern, you could take a look at this amazing post from *Dan Abramov* - Redux creator: https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0 . This is a part of that post:

> You’ll find your components much easier to reuse and reason about if you divide them into two categories. I call them Container and Presentational components* but I also heard Fat and Skinny, Smart and Dumb, Stateful and Pure, Screens and Components, etc. These all are not exactly the same, but the core idea is similar.

Comment: Quick tip, when you have non-dynamic input values, you can omit the brackets and single quotes: `title="users"`